# error when running "rails s" in ruby getting (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

i am new to ruby on rails.I successfully installed it but when i type the rails s command i get

/home/banished/Desktop/myrails/mynewproject/bin/spring:11:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`path_separator' for Gem:Module ('NoMethodError')
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in`'
i got this error after installing the mysql libary.I suspect they may be related
I tried google searching but i have not found enough responses addressing this issue
please any help??

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly same error when I tried to run blog example from: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

My bin/rails file was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

I thought that it should point to spring file that is in the same directory so I changed that.

```
<   load File.expand_path('./spring', __FILE__)
---
>   load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
```

after that I managed to start server

```
haahu@haahudev:~/workspace/rails/blog$ bin/rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-03-15 08:45:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-03-15 08:45:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-03-15 08:45:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2977 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-15 08:45:52 +0200
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (63.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 84.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2016-03-15 08:45:54] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

It might be so that this fix is not enough because my bin/rails file is still having similar path reference in APP_PATH

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
```

but I think that it will be a new kind of error message :-)